# What happens when forced into the enemy Hall of Storms in HotS?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In Heroes of the Storm, if you try to walk into the enemy Hall of Storms, you get booted away.  What happens if an enemy tries to bring you in via forced movement like Dehaka's Drag or Stitch's Gorge?  Does the effect immediately break? Do you just get booted out after it ends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes it breaks.**

I had this happen to me quite a few times, the hook grabs me to the hall and I would be kicked back in range of the nexus.

Additionally, if you try to jump into it you will also get kicked out.